# How do you access a Parse.com object's keys/value pairs after it has been returned by a query?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, parse-platform

I realize this is question probably has a simple answer, but I have failed to find it after looking through all relevant documentation at Parse.com and many other resources. Here is the snippet of code I am looking at:

```
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ProfileInfo"];
    [query whereKey:@"userID" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        /* What is the easiest way to pull the key/value pairs from the returned NSArray of PFobjects here? */
    }];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(PFObject *pfObject in objects){
    NSString *someValue = [pfObject objectForKey:@"someKey"];

    //or if it's a number
    NSNumber *someNumber = [pfObject objectForKey:@"someOtherKey"];
}
```